# ConnectedRouter redirects to '/' on page reload on initial render

Tags: reactjs, redux, connected-react-router

I have a React-Redux App with React-Router and `connected-react-router` (to be able to change location within redux actions):

```
const main = () => {
  hydrate(
    <AppContainer warnings={false}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <Switch>
            {renderRoutes(routes)}
          </Switch>
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>
    </AppContainer>,
    mountApp
  );
};
```

To change location in redux actions I do this:

```
import { push } from 'connected-react-router';
...
export const gotoProjects = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(push('/projects'));
  };
};
```

This works fine, but I encounter a behavior that I do not understand:

When I trigger a location via a redux action, everything works fine.
But when I reload a page (= browser refresh) with url `/projects` then a `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` action to `/` is dispatched.

And this location change only happens in `production` mode. 
In `development` mode (with `react-hot-loader`) the url is loaded correctly.

If I replace `ConnectedRouter` by `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom` everything is fine in both `production` and `development` mode.

On initial render of a route the history object looks like this (as expected):

```
{
  "history": {
    "length": 6,
    "action": "POP",
    "location": {
      "pathname": "/projects",
      "search": "",
      "hash": ""
    }
  }
}
```

But somehow the `ConnectedRouter` does a redirect.

Any help most welcome!

---

Edited: here is the routes code:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: '/projects',
    exact: true,
    component: Projects,
  },

  ...
];
```

Comment: Could you show your routing schema?

Comment: @Spacemoose: I have edited my question and added the routes code

Comment: same issue, did you find a fix?

Comment: I had the same issue and the solution is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57673356/react-router-issue-typing-any-url-in-address-bar-redirects-to/57708416#57708416

Comment: did you fix it??