# React router issue: typing any url in address bar redirects to /

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm having an issue with react-router. If I type random route in address bar (mysite.com/users (valid url to users page) or mysite.com/adf (definitely not valid url), which should show 404page), router redirects me to home page ('/'). If I click on Link which leads on same page, everything is fine, the necessary page is shown.

```
  {
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    cache: false,
    component: HomePage,
  },
  {
    path: '/users',
    exact: true,
    cache: false,
    component: UsersPage,
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    exact: true, // I tried both true and false
    cache: false,
    component: NotFoundPage,
    // also I tried to leave only component here
  },
```

then I render routes with `renderRoutes` func from `react-router-config`

```
  <Switch location={location}>
    {renderRoutes(routes, { ...someParams })}
  </Switch>
```

I want router not to redirect me and show needed page if I type in address bar valid url, like mysite.com/users and to show not found page, if I type in address bar invalid url, like mysite.com/asd

**UPD:** The problem is only with ConnectedRouter, if I use react-router-dom Router everything is fine

Comment: Post complete `routes`.

Comment: it's complete routes

Comment: Check this doc - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-config. `renderRoutes` needs array of object.

Comment: Did you analyse your router examples with `matchRoutes()`?

Comment: I passed an array of object, just copied only objects. The problem is deeper

Comment: Yes I did match routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was in Switch. You don't have to use it, because renderRoutes has it's own Switch and you can pass switch params as third argument, like `{renderRoutes(routes, { ...someParams }, { ...switchParams })}`